# Cocos2d JS mixed font label

Tags: ios, label, cocos2d-js

In Cocos2d JS, we can use `LabelTTF` to create label, and give it a font.

How can we create mixed font labels, example, "This **is my** Name".

1.) I should be a able to change color, font, and size of text. Equivalent of this in objective-c is NSAttributedString.

2.) Alternatively, can we display html text in cocos2d-js.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are features like these in the works for v4, but for now there's not an easy way.

You'll have to create your own class, which internally keeps several `LabelTTF`s, one for each portion of differently formatted text, and sorts them properly within the desired space.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, will look forward to v4.

Answer (score 1):

it's called richtext.

this is the sample codes:

```
 var richText = new ccui.RichText();
var text1 = new ccui.RichElementText(1, cc.color.RED, 255, "HELLO", "Arial", 25);
var text2 = new ccui.RichElementText(1, cc.color.GREEN, 255, "HELLO", "Arial", 35);

richText.pushBackElement(text1);
richText.pushBackElement(text2);
richText.setPosition(cc.p(200,200));
this.addChild(richText);
```

look at [here](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-html5/blob/8bfc3f5ac8ea900561337d65ec5487929d883188/extensions/ccui/uiwidgets/UIRichText.js)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer for your second question:

Basically what you see in the output screen is from the HTML file. There is an element in it in which our cocos2dJS output is seen. So., my idea is... 
You can create the labels or div with different id names. And style has to be as follows:

```
idName{display: none; position: fixed;}
```

Once you require your div or label to be shown, you can access it by the following code and Display it on your screen:

```
document.getElementById('idName').style.display = 'block';
```

If you want to position it at a correct place use the following code:

```
document.getElementById('idName').style.top = cc.winSize.height/2;//This value can be as you wanted to display. 
document.getElementById('idName').style.left = cc.winSize.width/2;//This value can be as you wanted to display.
```

Now that's the Complete scene. You are done with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need this link:
https://docs.cocos2d-x.org/api-ref/js/V2.2/symbols/cc.LabelTTF.html

This is a documentation from cocos2d-x and a below is a example:

```js
var lbCoin =  new cc.LabelTTF( '123.456.789',           /* content */
                               'Arial',                 /* font family */
                               24,                      /* font size */
                               cc.size(0, 0),           /* position */
                               cc.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT); /* alignment */
lbCoin.attr({
     x: cc.winSize.width / 2,
     y: cc.winSize.height / 2
});

lbCoin.zIndex = 2005;
lbCoin.color = cc.color(250, 221, 149); 
// or you can use lbCoin.setColor(cc.color(250, 221, 149));
this.addChild(this.lbCoin);
```